# Break logical lines

Tags: multiple-lines

I'm looking for a way to make a line be *only logically* broken at the end of the available space. Here's an example: let's suppose I have a really long line (i.e. a string without any `\n` in it), and to render it on the screen, ViM must split it, so, by turning on line numbers I see

```
1: This is the beginning of my very very very long line that does not fit 
ViM's window and therefore it must be split into two lines.
2: And this is another line of text
```

Now, if I'm in normal mode, I can move from line 1 to line 2 by using `j`, but I have no ways to move from the word "beginning" to the word "therefore", apart from `gj` which I find slow. I tried to remap `j` to `gj`, only for the filetypes I'm interested in (I wouldn't ever do this with C source files for example), but this gives me another issue: relative numbers do not work anymore. If I'm on line 1 and type `d1j` only the first two "logical lines" are deleted (which in my example they correspond to the whole line 1). So I'm looking for a way to move inside the lines pretending they're logical lines (i.e. by `gj`ing  or `gk`ing) and work with the physical lines.

I tried with the `textwidth` option, but it physically breaks the lines, so it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your sentence about d1j is confusing—only the first two logical lines... (what)? If you want dj to work normally, dont omap j; if you want dj == dgj, you have to omap j

Comment: @D.BenKnoble As a logical line, I mean a line that is split by ViM and not by a \n. So what physically on the file is a single line (i.e. a string of characters followed by a \n), in the ViM editor, depending on the size of the window, can become more than one line of text. I call logical line the line of text I see in the ViM editor before it wraps it and makes the rest of the line go in another one. Anyway, thanks to you and the answer by husB, I figured out the problem and solved it.

Comment: glad you solved your problem, but im not sure you understood my question—your sentence about d1j is logically and grammatically incomplete. It effectively reads “if i do X, only the first two logical lines.” Do you see how there’s something missing? Only the first two logical lines... what? What do they or should they do?

Comment: ..."are deleted". I'm sorry about it, but I did not notice it. Sorry for the inconvenience. :-( I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: no problem! Nothing to worry about—glad you got it squared away!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two solutions to this:

### 1:  Use normal mode mappings only; do not use an operator-pending mode mapping

As @D.Ben Knoble mentioned in his comment, instead of

```
noremap j gj
noremap k gk
```

use

```
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap k gk
```

The former maps `j` and `k` in normal, visual, and operator-pending modes, while the latter maps `j` and `k` only in normal mode. With the latter mappings, after an operator (such as `d`, `c`, or `y`), `j` and `k` remain as-is.

---

### 2: Use an expression mapping to check if a count is given

```
noremap <expr> j v:count ? 'j' : 'gj'
noremap <expr> k v:count ? 'k' : 'gk'
```

These check if a count has been supplied. If there is a count, `j` or `k` is used; otherwise `gj` or `gk` is used.

In this way, `1j` or `1k` moves up or down a whole line, while `j` or `k` moves up or down a screen line.

---

For more information, see

- `:h map-modes`
- `:h map-expression`
- `:h count-variable`